# IOS Components From Date Changes Timezone

Tags: ios, nsdate, nsdatecomponents

I am using

```
NSDateComponents *components = [CURRENT_CALENDAR components:DATE_COMPONENTS fromDate:_startDate];
[components setHour:0];
[components setMinute:0];
[components setSecond:0];
_date = [CURRENT_CALENDAR dateFromComponents:components];
```

With dates I receive from an API.

The _date returns 2 different outputs depending on the calendar day:

```
2016-01-04 05:00:00 +0000
2015-10-26 04:00:00 +0000
```

As if there was a change in time zone.

Is there a reason the time of _date changes from 5 to 4 ?Is there something to prevent that?

Problem is that unexpected time offset (-1) reflects in all the other dates I create with dateFromComponents:components

Output for different dates showing the offset

```
2016-01-04 05:00:00 +0000
2015-12-21 05:00:00 +0000
2015-12-14 05:00:00 +0000
2015-12-07 05:00:00 +0000
2015-11-23 05:00:00 +0000
2015-11-16 05:00:00 +0000
2015-11-09 05:00:00 +0000
2015-11-02 05:00:00 +0000
2015-10-26 04:00:00 +0000
2015-10-19 04:00:00 +0000
2015-10-22 04:00:00 +0000
2015-10-01 04:00:00 +0000
2015-09-24 04:00:00 +0000
```

Comment: "As if there was a change in time zone" - what are you expecting exactly?

Comment: The time to stay the same : 05:00:00 +0000

Comment: The actual date and the date that we see in NSLog varies. Don't worry about that.

Comment: `daylight saving time` issue?

Comment: Note: In 2015, the daylight saving time at the end of the year happens the during the night of 25th and 26th of October.